# Why text changing size

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, web

When I change size of display in ¨Show code¨ mode in Google Chrome text changing size, but I set font-size 30px [Big screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tHknh.png)  [Small screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ysJAo.png)

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<nav id="head-menu">
  <ul id="head-bar">
      <li> <p href="#">Sobre nos</a></li> 
      <li> <a href="#">Menú</a> </li> 
      <li> <a href="#">Galería</a> </li> 
      <li> <a href="#">Contactos</a> </li> 
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Result always the same and I can't understand why

Comment: I made this into a runnable snippet so that I could test it.  If I expand the snippet to run it full screen in chrome, open up the dev tools, use responsive mode, and change the size, the font stays the same size.  I'm not able to reproduce your problem.

Comment: I couldn't reproduce the issue that you are talking about, The font size seems to be normal